# unable to use IP address with ftplib (Python)

Tags: python, ftp-client, ftplib

I have created an FTP client using ftplib. I am running the server on one of my Ubuntu virtual machine and client on another. I want to connect to the server using ftplib and I'm doing it in the following way:

```
host = "IP address of the server"
port = "Port number of the server" 

ftpc = FTP()
ftpc.connect(host, port)
```

I'm getting the following error!

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./client.py", line 54, in <module>
    ftpc.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 132, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

When I went through the docs of python, I could see ftplib used only with domain names as in FTP("domain name"). Can I use IP address instead of domain name? In my case I am unable to comprehend the error. It would be great if anyone can help me out.

Also if I use port 21 on my server, I'm getting socket error: Connection refused. How do I use port 21 for my FTP server?

Thank You.

Comment: connection refused means that your code actually reached the remote address, but that machine either is NOT running an ftp server, or the port's firewalled away. using a dns name mean nothing - it's simply an abstraction layer. everything runs on IPs under the hood anyways.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do I check if the port's firewalled?

Comment: on the server hosting the FTP server, run `iptables --list` as `root`, or `sudo iptables --list`.

Comment: From the output I can see its all accept. Does it mean its not firewalled?

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: from the client machine try using the ftp command line client to manually ftp and see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to connect to SFTP server using ftplib which is giving you the Connection Refused error. Try using pysftp instead of ftplib and see if it works.

On the virtual machine, test by typing ftp and sftp commands on the console. You will get to know on which server the machine is running i.e ftp or sftp.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I install and config vsftpd:

1. sudo apt install vsftpd (if not exist)
2. sudo vim /etc/vsftpd.conf
3. set "listen=YES"